# Database link for Azure SQL to Azure Synapse Anayltics Serverless SQL Pool

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

A client of mine needs to join tables from his Azure SQL financial data mart with external tables built upon a Data Lakehouse (Parquet files) in Azure Synapse Analytics.

I was wondering if it's possible to create a **database link** within a **Azure SQL database** accessing a **Azure Synapse Analytics *Serverless*** (on-demand) SQL Pool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s possible open the Integrate hub, and select and add a link connection.

- Select test connection and make sure to check whether SQL firewall rules are properly configured or not.

[image: Ref1]

**Reference:**

[Get started with Azure Synapse Link for Azure SQL Database (Preview) - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/synapse-link/connect-synapse-link-sql-database#create-the-azure-synapse-link-connection)